# Set a global variable in other function

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables

I am trying to set the value of area and perimeter variable that are calculated in "on_button" function and use those in labels. I am confused with using global in the code, because some says its not good.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.area = 0
        self.widthLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Width:")
        self.widthLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.widthEntry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.widthEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.heightLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Height:")
        self.heightLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.heightEntry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.heightEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        #self.areaValLabel = tk.StringVar()
        #self.areaValLabel.set(0)

        self.areaLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Area:").grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.areaValLabel = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.area).grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.PerLabel = tk.Label(self,text="Perimeter:").grid(row=4, column=0)
        #self.perValLabel =tk.Label(self, text=perimeter).grid(row=4, column=1)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Calculate", command=self.on_button).grid(row=2, column=0)

def on_button(self):
        print self.widthEntry.get()
        print self.heightEntry.get()
        width = self.widthEntry.get()
        height = self.heightEntry.get()
        print float(width)*float(height)
        self.area.set(float(width)*float(height))


app = SampleApp()
app.title("HW1")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix your indents

Comment: What's your question? If i fix the indentation, uncomment the `self.area` lines and change `text=self.area` to `textvariable=self.area`, calculating the area seems to work fine and you're not using globals. So what exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: @ cwallenpoole fixed the indents. thanks for letting me know.@ fhdrsdg I am trying to get the value that is entered to the entries and show the result on areaValLabel.

Comment: If you take the code as it was when you first posted it and change only what I mentioned in my previous comment, it'll work.

Answer (score -3):

You can access the variables like so:

```
self.area.set(float(self.width)*float(self.height))
```

Even outside you can do something like:

```
object.width
```

to get the value of the parameters. No need for global :)

Comment: There is no `self.width` attribute.